# VBS (Visual Basic Script) Run Program hidden/invisible

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to run a program (In this case Internet Explore) hidden/invisible from a VB script.

I found a simple script for making batch files hidden, and tried it. It didn't seem to work as the program just popped up as normal.

Here is my code so far:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "iexplore.exe",0,True
```

This runs the program iexplore.exe, but doesn't run it hidden/invisible.

I am also running this VBS file from a batch file which is hidden.
The batch file simply does:

```
start Run.vbs
```

Codes of each script/batch file:

**Batch File: Main file launching VBS file**

```
@echo off
:start
start HideExecuteServerVBS.vbs (To Hide the ExecuteServerVBS.bat file when running)
timeout /NOBREAK /T 5
TASKKILL /IM iexplore.exe
timeout /NOBREAK /T 3
TASKKILL /IM iexplore.exe /F
timeout /NOBREAK /T 1800
goto start
```

**HideExecuteServerVBS.vbs**

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "ExecuteServerVBS.bat",0,True
```

**ExecuteServerVBS.vbs**

```
@echo off
C:\Windows\sysWOW64\csript.exe C:\Users\Admin\RunInternetProcess\vbscript.vbs
```

**vbscript.vbs**

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Is there a possible way to run a program invisible through a VB Script (Visual Basic Script)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's the deal, if you are receiving an ActiveX error, you most likely are trying to run this vbscript under a server. Server with a 64bit platform with lack of support for direct execution of 32bit vbscripts? Yeah? If so, here's what you need to do.

Make a batch file:
ExecuteServerVBS.bat

```
C:\windows\sysWOW64\cscript.exe C:\path\to\your\vbscript.vbs
```

Put your vbscript code here:

vbscript.vbs

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'Go crazy
```

And BOOM. You're done.

**UPDATE**

update the file `ExecuteServerVBS.vbs`

```
@echo off
C:\Windows\sysWOW64\cscript.exe C:\Users\Admin\RunInternetProcess\vbscript.vbs > errorlog.log
```

update the file `vbscript.vbs`

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim ie 
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
'Perform IE functions here......
If err.number <> 0 then wscript.echo err.number & ":" & err.description
```

Comment: So the code for the "ExecuteServerVBS.bat" would be "C:\windows\sysWOW64\script.exe C:\path\to\my\vbscript.vbs"?

Comment: So then code for the "ExecuteServerVBS.bat" would be "C:\windows\sysWOW64\cscript.exe C:\path\to\my\vbscript.vbs"?

Comment: Yes. No luck? Theres additional info on executing vbs on a aerver in the vbscript info page.

Comment: By the way, I'm not running a server.

Comment: For some reason, when it launches it opens a new tab in the browser I am currently in (Not Default browser, not internet explorer).

Comment: Full code of what? The VBS file or the main batch file running the VBS file?

Comment: Both, in your question please.

Comment: does vbscript.vbs = hideexecuteservervbs.vbs?

Comment: No, I will add the vbscript.vbs. Forgot it, sorry.

Comment: Ok cool. Update your files according to my instructions above and let me know the error description after you run it. If it runs successfully, let me know and i'll rewrite the above code so it runs quietly.

Comment: Says it successfully attached to the IE dll.

Comment: Still opens a new tab in this browser though.

Comment: It works when I do not have this browser open, but when I do it opens another tab.

Comment: Yeah it's going to do that if you don't specify that you want it as invisible. Let me update my code. one sec

Comment: Ok, try the code out in the section above. It should activate without opening a new tab. Make sure you keep the error handling in your code and it will output too errorlog.log after you update your batch file with my suggestion as well. And you should be good to go!

Comment: Now it works fine when I run the vbscript.vbs file directly, but not when I run the batch file that executes the ExecuteServerVbs.bat.

Comment: Yeah, most likely because the Shell.Run command doesn't like the command output i put in " > errorlog.log", if you remove that i'm sure it won't be a problem. Regardless, you got what you needed? Can I get a big green check mark FTW? :D

Comment: Removed the "> errorlog.log", but it still opens in a new tab =/

Comment: I ran it and could not resimulate your issue. Are you trying to navigate the current iexplore session?

Comment: No, I am on another browser but it opens a new tab on that browser rather than opening Internet Explorer.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you should just not run a browser while your executing it then. No idea why it's triggering that for you. That's your machines problem for sure. I'm running lots of browsers as i'm currently designing websites and then did not happen with me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load it this way instead:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

' To make visible, uncomment the following line...
'ie.Visible = True
```

Comment: I get an error, "ActiveX component can't create object: 'InternetExplorer.Application' Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error"

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit OS? If so, try using WSCRIPT.EXE from the SysWow64 folder to launch your script.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: How would I use WSCRIPT.EXE to launch my script?

Comment: A few ways. One way is to just right-click your VBS file, choose "Open With", and then navigate to your c:\windows\syswow64 folder and choose WSCRIPT.EXE from there.

Comment: You can also just open your SysWow64 folder in My Computer (Windows Explorer) and then drag and drop your VBS file on top of WSCRIPT.EXE.

Comment: I would need to do that manually every time, it couldn't be automatic from the batch file.

Comment: If you're launching your script from a batch file, then just run `c:\windows\syswow64\wscript.exe "c:\path\script.vbs"`.

Comment: We were trying that, but it doesn't seem to be working. See the answer by Rich.

Comment: Test the script on its own by using one of the methods I mentioned above. Does it work that way?

Comment: Doesn't seem to, same issue as on the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these methods:

http://ss64.com/vb/run.html

http://ss64.com/vb/exec.html

http://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html

http://ss64.com/vb/syntax-elevate.html