# Run iexplore.exe invisibly

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run iexplore.exe invisibly. This works but it shows the internet explorer window.

```
@Start iexplore www.google.com
```

Than I tried it with /d

```
@Start /d iexplore www.google.com
```

But I'm getting "The current directory is invalid" error. What is the correct way to run iexplore via bat file invisibly ?

Comment: Why do you need to run a web browser (designed to **display** web pages) invisibly?

Comment: Because its a tracking software and no need to be displayed. No, its not a malware.

Comment: It sounds like you want wget.

Comment: It's malware if you're using it without the user's knowledge to do something.

Comment: Again "why are you doing that" replies. Not looking cool from a 74,000 rep member. Just going off-topic, nothing more.

Comment: @user198989 Because SO members generally refrain from helping questions that are ethically suspicious.

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698508/vbs-visual-basic-script-run-program-hidden-invinsible

Answer (score 1):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run """c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore"" www.google.com", 0, false
```

Put in a file called HiddenGoogle.vbs

0 means hidden - there is about 12 options

false means don't wait. True means wait.

Typing this in a command prompt will allow you to check on your hidden window. You can tell which one it is by the window title.

```
tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq iexplore.exe"
```

or

```
tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq iexplore.exe" /fi "windowtitle eq Google - Windows Internet Explorer"
```

**Just type the name of the vbs file to run it. Either in command prompt or in a batch file.**

```
"c:\some folder\hiddengoogle.vbs"
```

That's all.

Comment: Thanks. So you say I need to run vbs file ? Is it possible to run in bat ?