# Close a Window in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, startup

Hey I've got a quick question,

I know that you can start applications minimized through the command prompt with something like:

> start /min "" "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"

However is there a way to automatically close the window, now I don't mean kill the process/task. Just close the window. In notepads case this would work the same way as killing the process, but in something that will minimize to a system tray on a window close, like Skype, or Discord for example this wouldn't kill the process but instead just put the task away from sight.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, right after the application has launched, just close it. So you'll only see it very briefly and then it will disappear

Comment: I suppose this is a very specific request, however the app I am trying to minimize will essentially ignore any minimize or start silent command because it has a splash screen. So if I start it minimized this will only minimize the splash screen and still boot the application in fullscreen

Comment: Would it be possible to use one of the 'key recording apps' to record a `macro` that is then used to start the application minimized?

Comment: You could use a key recording app like @RyanVincent suggested or you could launch it hidden completely using a VBScript - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22700462/5269570

Comment: You opted for the wrong solution due to wrong assumptions. Closing a window is a destructive operation. The window is gone, but the process is also broken, if it doesn't expect random programs killing their windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in batch files alone, instead this script creates a temporary VBScript at `%temp%\hidden.vbs` and then passes arguments to it using `wscript.exe`

This script doesn't minimise it or send it to the system tray, it just hides it and is only visible in Task Manager

```
@echo off
(echo CreateObject^("Wscript.Shell"^).Run """" ^& WScript.Arguments^(0^) ^& """", 0, False) > "%temp%\hidden.vbs"
set launch=wscript.exe "%temp%\hidden.vbs"


%launch% notepad
```